# Printing console command exactly how I entered it

Tags: python, printing, console, command

I'm having issues with console commands.

```
import re
import string
import sys
import subprocess


productname= "".join(sys.argv[1:])

def check():
    global productname
    productname= productname.replace(' ','')
    productname= productname.replace('\n','')

    if len(productname) >= 3:
        print "Product name: %s" %(sys.argv[1:None])

check()
```

Right now when I enter in `python test.py a a  a  s` in the console command line, it prints out:

```
Product name: ['a', 'a', 'a', 's']
```

I want it so that it prints the output out exactly how I entered it in. How do I do that?

So basically the output should be:
`Product name: a a  a   s`

That's: a (space) a (space)(space) a (space)(space) s

My inputs will vary in spaces sometimes, so i cant have it hardcoded with

```
' '.join(sys.argv[1:None]))..
```

Comment: `" ".join(sys.argv[1:])`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your exact input, you could enter it on the command line as:

```
python test.py "a a  a  s"
```

This means that `argv[1]` will be the entire string `"a a  a  s"`, so code like this would work:

```
productname = sys.argv[1]

# Other stuff

# Use .split() to get the number of letters in the string.
if len(productname.split()) >= 3:
    print "Product name: %s" % (productname)
```

This will ensure you get the exact same string, including spaces, as you inputted, which you can then clean and modify as you wish.

Comment: My mistake, forgot to change the final line of code to reflect the fix. Hope this works better for you.

Comment: How do I get rid of the [] and the ' in the output?

Comment: @Nikkibee - If it's doing that, the string you're interested in is still in a list. Retrieve the actual element as this answer describes.

Comment: Yes, if you copy my code as it is here and enter the string like you described and with the quotes, the answer *will* be correct. Either you're entering a list (as a string) like @TigerhawkT3 said or your code doesn't match mine. I've checked the code on my machine and it works like you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

That's because by default, the array is coerced to string in that format. (Because of the `%s` formatter you're using.)

If you want something else, convert the array to the string you want first. A simple solution for you would be `' '.join(sys.argv[1:None])`.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The OP wants to preserve the whitespace sent in from the command line as a single string, rather than automatically splitting on whitespace into a list and prettyprinting it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, that is what I need.